# Permalink to a git branch

Tags: git, dropbox

One advantage to an SVN branching model is that all of your branches have distinct files. I'd like to share one of my git branches over Dropbox, but if I switched branches in git, all of the files would get overwritten in the Dropbox. Is there a way to permanently link to files in a branch?

I guess I could clone the whole repo again into a different folder, but this seems inefficient.

Comment: You'd have to have a checkout from SVN of whichever branch you wanted, also.. you can't just link in to the `.svn/` folder.

Comment: The SVN branch is more like a whole Git repository than a Git branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store a "bare" Git repository in Dropbox, and then anybody who has read access to your Dropbox can make a clone locally. They will be able to choose which branch to check out after they clone it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a work-tree (checkout) at any location on the filesystem.  This will enable you to checkout a given branch to any location, it will not be affected by further checkins or checkouts:

```
cd ~/Dropbox/mysharedbranchdir
git --git-dir ~/path/to/repo checkout mybranch
```